# JQuery Mobile / Opera Mini - Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, opera

I have a mobile site built with JQuery mobile (and of course JQuery). At the start of my own javascript file I have this error logging code:

```
"use strict";

window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    remoteConsoleLog(errorMsg, 'window onerror ' + url);
}

function remoteConsoleLog(msgToLog, msgDesc) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/php/mobile_log_javascript_events.php',
    data: JSON.stringify({UA: navigator.userAgent, MSG: msgToLog, MSGDESC: msgDesc}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });
}
```

This enables me to log (to my server) javascript errors the end users get.

I am seeing this error for Opera Mini users (various versions)

```
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: filters
```

Looking at the JQuery source I see 'filters' is referenced many times, and it is not in use with my own code, so can only assume there is some issue with Opera Mini.

I have tried it out myself with these versions (basically all current as of today):

JQuery 1.11.1
JQuery Mobile 1.4.5
Opera Mini/15.0.2125

Not seeing this error with any other browsers.

Comment: We started getting this in our sentry errors too. Started happening March 31st. Across multiple smartphones and multiple versions of Opera Mini browsers. Doesn't seem to show up under any other conditions

Comment: I've seen it since something like 23 March when I went live with this. Wonder if it could be Opera's proxy server?

Comment: You're right. I've started seeing this on multiple websites on Opera Mini starting March 31st. The issue is definitely with Opera Mini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug on the server side of Opera Mini. This should not affect your code in any way. Anyway, we are going to fix the issue soon, so you don't get unnecessary notifications.

Comment: Thanks for that, and yes, my site does appear to work correctly as is. I saw your post on the Opera forum too, thanks.